How to change a specific property for all instances of the class with one command
Here is the code.
class average_person:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, height, weight, email):
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.email = email

        self.email = self.first_name + '.' + self.last_name + email

    def doc(self):
        print(f"Name: {self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name} Height: {self.height} Weight: {self.weight}, Email: {self.email}")

    def mail(self):
        print(f"Email: {self.email}")

    def change_email(self, gmail):
        self.email = self.first_name + '.' + self.last_name + gmail
        print(self.email)

    


# Create 5 instances of the class

person_1 = average_person("Abu Bakr", "Hassan", "5'6", "122 lbs", '@gmail.com')
person_2 = average_person("Syed", "Jameel", "5'2", "99 lbs", '@cpsaonline.org')
person_3 = average_person("Abdur-Rahman", "Mohammed", "4'10", "100 lbs", '@gmail.com')
person_4 = average_person("Haroon", "Abdul-Mannan", "4'11", "98 lbs", '@company.org')
person_5 = average_person("Bilal", "Ala", "5'1", "101 lbs", '@cpsa.school')

# Running the functions


The code runs fine. I just don't know how to change a specific property or variable of the instances(I want to change the email) with one separate command that affects all instances of the class.
At first I thought maybe I could use @classmethods but I have no idea what I'm doing so that really didn't go anywhere. I just need to know what to do and an explanation for why it works.

Well, I consider it impossible as each instance is isolated. Try use for and eval instead.

You should have a list of average_person instances, not 5 separate variables.

You can do it. You need to create a list within the class to keep track of the instances.
Then you can create a for loop within a classmethod inside the class.
You will have to define it before hand though. Use a class variable to store the shared value and a classmethod to set and update all the instances.
You can do it like this.

class AveragePerson:
    shared_email_domain = None
    instances = []

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, height, weight, email):
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.email = email

        self.email = self.first_name + '.' + self.last_name + self.email
        AveragePerson.instances.append(self)

    def doc(self):
        print(f"Name: {self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name} Height: {self.height} Weight: {self.weight}, Email: {self.email}")

    def mail(self):
        print(f"Email: {self.email}")

    @classmethod
    def set_shared_email_domain(cls, domain):
        cls.shared_email_domain = domain

    @classmethod
    def change_all_emails(cls):
        if cls.shared_email_domain:
            for instance in cls.instances:
                instance.email = instance.first_name + '.' + instance.last_name + cls.shared_email_domain
        else:
            print("Shared email domain is not set.")


person_1 = AveragePerson("Abu Bakr", "Hassan", "5'6", "122 lbs", '@gmail.com')
person_2 = AveragePerson("Syed", "Jameel", "5'2", "99 lbs", '@cpsaonline.org')
person_3 = AveragePerson("Abdur-Rahman", "Mohammed", "4'10", "100 lbs", '@gmail.com')
person_4 = AveragePerson("Haroon", "Abdul-Mannan", "4'11", "98 lbs", '@company.org')
person_5 = AveragePerson("Bilal", "Ala", "5'1", "101 lbs", '@cpsa.school')

AveragePerson.set_shared_email_domain("@example.com")

AveragePerson.change_all_emails()



I have tested it and it works. You can print your variables after running this using this code and see for yourself.
for person in [person_1, person_2, person_3, person_4, person_5]:
    print(person.email)


This was exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate it. I can't emphasize enough how much this helped.

If you had a class variable it would be shared between all instances of the class, then changing that attribute causes all the instances to see the updated attribute. But instance variables are for each individual instances and they are not shared.
There is no built-in functionality in the language for doing so. You need to manually update each one. Ideally if they are all present somewhere like a container object(list, tuple, ...) you can update them in a loop. This container can be anywhere, in a module or inside the class namespace.
